# Preprocessors and use association

Tags: module, preprocessor, fortran

In summary, is it possible to access via use association a preprocessor directive defined in a Fortran module?

**Context**

I use preprocessor statements to define subroutines to print warning and error messages. For example, I use the following module/subroutine, in the file `errors.f`, to print warning messages

```
module errors
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only : error_unit=>stderr
  implicit none
  contains

    !> Print formatted warning message.
    subroutine warn_print( file, line, mesg )
      implicit none
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: file
      integer,          intent(in) :: line
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: mesg

      write(stderr,'(a,a,a,i4,a,a)') "WARNING::", file, ":", line, ": ", mesg

  end subroutine warn_print

end module errors
```

and, in a separate file `errors.h`, I `use` the above module and define a preprocessor macro

```
use errors

#define warn( text )warn_print(__FILE__,__LINE__,text)
```

I then `#include` the file `errors.h` in whichever file/module I wish to use the warning print routine which allows me to simply write

```
call warn("Some warning message")
```

and the compiler will automatically include the file and line number at which the warning message was called.

**Question**

The use of `#include 'errors.h'` is rather idiosyncratic in Fortran code and it hides the `use` of the `errors` module. Ideally I would prefer to define the above preprocessor in the errors module itself. However, then when using that module, this preprocessor directive is not available to the program/module which `use`s this module.

Is there a way to make a preprocessor directive accessible via use association?

The only other way I can think of doing it is to just have the errors module and define the preprocessor directive in my call to the compiler (using, for example, the `-D` flag with ifort). Any suggestions for any alternative way of achieving the above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is simply not possible, since the preprocessing and the compilation stages are completely separate one from each other and the C preprocessor does not know anything about the Fortran USE statement.

I use to #include 'config.h' (from autoconf) in most of my .F90 sources, without problems.

Comment: I thought as much, which is why I use the set up I describe in my question. I was hoping to get other peoples suggestions for different schemes for implementing a function which prints the file and line number from which it was called. Welcome to So!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you are looking for, but if you are using ifort, you can use traceback functionality to achieve something similar (a bit more powerful, but also more ugly), e.g.

```
program tracetest
  call sub(5)
  write(*,*) '=== DONE ==='
end program tracetest

subroutine sub(n)
  use ifcore
  integer :: n
  character(len=60) :: str
  write(str,*) '=== TROUBLE DETECTED: n =',n  ! code -1 means "do not abort"      
  call tracebackqq(str,-1)    
end subroutine sub
```

Then, compile with `-traceback` to see the source file, line, and stack trace. The stack trace and line may be obscured because of inlining; to avoid that, you can specify `-traceback -O0` to get smth like this:

```
=== TROUBLE DETECTED: n =           5                      
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source             
a.out              0000000000473D0D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000472815  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000423260  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000404BD6  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000000402C14  sub_                       12  tracetest.f90
a.out              0000000000402B18  MAIN__                      2  tracetest.f90
a.out              0000000000402ADC  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc.so.6          000000323201EC5D  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              00000000004029D9  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
=== DONE ===
```

Alternatively, if want to keep the optimizations, and also want to see the correct line (12), you can compile with (for example) `-fast -traceback -debug all,inline_debug_info`. Something similar may be available in other compilers, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks @laxxy - I had no idea about this. It is a good answer, but unfortunately not portable. It would be interesting to see if anyway has an equivalent/similar portable version of this functionality.